# Webpart zone is not appearing on publishing page

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

I have created a page in the pages library with a Page layout. In that layout I have added a webpart zone with the snippets.

That webpart zone is not appearing when I edit the page. Do I need to activate any feature for this?

Comment: Are you sure, you are not getting any error?

Comment: No error is coming

Comment: Do you have any custom master page applied to it? If it is, try resetting the master page and then check the page whether the web part zone is appearing or not?

Comment: Yes I am having the custom master page. Even i tried with resetting. still the behavior is same. Webparts are hidden. I opened developer tools and checked. Webparts are there but those are in hidden state.

Comment: I am sure some of your style is hiding those web part, did you check that?

Comment: But it is working in google chrome

Answer (score 2):

In IE, add the SharePoint website URL to the 'compatibility view settings'. You will then start to see the web part zones appear.